# How to get the prediction output from glmmPQL to work with performance using R?

Tags: r, prediction, predict

### Problem

I am using R 3.3.3 on Windows 10 (x64 bit). I get the following prediction output from the glmmPQL prediction function as follows:

```
library(MASS)
library(nlme) 
library(dplyr)
```

`model<-glmmPQL(a ~ b + c + d, data = trainingDataSet, family = binomial, random = list( ~ 1 | e), correlation = corAR1())`

The prediction values are given as follows:

`p <- predict(model, newdata=testingDataSet, type="response",level=0)` (1.0)

The output it gives is as follows:

[image]

I then try to measure the performance of this output using the following code:

`pr <- prediction(p, testingDataSet$a)`(1.1)

It gives us the following error as follows:

`Error in prediction(p, testingDataSet$a) : 
  Format of predictions is invalid.` (1.2)

I have successfully been able to use the prediction method in R using other functions (glm,svm,nn) when the data looks something like as follows:

`model<-glm(a ~ b + c + e, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = trainingDataSet)`

`p <- predict(model, newdata=testingDataSet, type="response")` (1.3)

[image: output from logistic predict]

### Attempts

I believe the fix to the above problem is to get it into the format shown below (1.3). I have tried the following things using R and have been failing.

I have tried casting `p` in `1.0` using `as.numeric()` and `as.list()` and other things. I want to get look like the `p` R object in `1.3`. In other words, I believe the format is reason why things not working for me?

No matter what mutate or casting I try, I can't seem to get it into the form in `1.3` and image shown as desired. Especially with the index as columns features. 
I'm coming up empty handed on stackoverflow and the R help files. When I use the command `class(p)` both tell me they are numeric.

### Question

Give the above, can someone tell me how I can use R to get the output from glmmPQL in a format that the prediction function can use as shown above please?

In other words, how can I make sure the output in `1.0` can made to match the output in `1.3` in R? My attempts have failed and I would deeply appreciate someone more skilled in R to point out where I am failing?

Comment: Are you using the library(MASS)?

Comment: I am using library(MASS) `#installs glmmPQL` 
library(nlme) `#installs corAR1`
library(dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use as.numeric(p) then you'll get the values you want - then the only difference is that the GLM output has names. You can add these in with something like:

```
p <- as.numeric(p)
names(p) <- 1:length(p)
```

If this doesn't work, you can use `str(p)` to examine the structure of the object in more depth.

Comment: Thank you. This was completely spot on and a concise answer. Thank you for taking the time to assist me.